# How to parameterise the curve $ x^2 = 4y, 3x^3 = 8z$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric

As per title, I'm unsure how to parameterise the given curve? Are there different methods? I'm unsure about parameterisation in general, I just tend to remember specific formulas.

Answer (score 2):

How about:
$$
r(t) =
\left[
\begin{matrix}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{matrix}
\right] =
\left[
\begin{matrix}
t \\
\frac{t^2}{4} \\
\frac{3t^3}{8} \\
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

for $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

More complicated it gets if you want to parameterise by the arc length $s$, with $ds^2=dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$.

Comment: Then how would I write out F in terms of the parameterisation?

Comment: What is your $F$?

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, I found F and realised how to write it out, thanks.

Comment: You are welcome.